# Arquillian configuration DeploymentException with WindowBeanHolder

Tags: java-ee-7, jboss-arquillian

I'm building a test suite in order to perform them on arquillian. I've followed this [Arquillian's starting guide](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/)
I'm using this gradle to test my tests:

```
providedCompile 'org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-7.0:1.0.3.Final'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-junit:2.0.0.0'
testCompile 'org.jglue.cdi-unit:cdi-unit:3.1.3'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.0.31-beta'
testCompile 'eu.codearte.catch-exception:catch-exception:2.0.0-ALPHA-1'
testCompile 'com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured:2.6.0'
testCompile 'com.carrotsearch:junit-benchmarks:0.7.2'

testCompile 'org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:1.1.9.Final'
testCompile 'org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:1.1.9.Final'
testCompile 'org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1:1.0.0.CR9'
testCompile 'org.jboss.weld:weld-core:2.3.0.Final'
testCompile 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-depchain:1.2.2'
testCompile 'org.apache.deltaspike.core:deltaspike-core-api:1.5.0'
testCompile 'org.apache.deltaspike.core:deltaspike-core-impl:1.5.0'
testCompile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.12'
```

when I perform my tests from Eclipse:

It dumps me an exception:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="environment" value="developmentorg.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
        Exception 0 :
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find beans for Type=class org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.scope.window.WindowBeanHolder and qualifiers:[]
            at org.apache.deltaspike.core.api.provider.BeanProvider.getContextualReference(BeanProvider.java:150)
            at org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.scope.DeltaSpikeContextExtension.initializeDeltaSpikeContexts(DeltaSpikeContextExtension.java:85)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 5):

Add

```
.addPackages(true, "org.apache.deltaspike")
```

to ShrinkWrap code.